# ServiceStack not deserializing Dictionary<string,object> properly

Tags: servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack v5.1.0 and here is the issue I'm having:
I have a DTO that looks like this:

```
    [Route("/TablesV2/{Id}/Query/{QueryId}/Edit", Verbs = "POST")]
    public class EditTableRecord : IReturn<object>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int QueryId { get; set; }
        public int ViewId { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, object> ParameterList { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, object> GlobalParamList { get; set; }


    }
```

Now when I do a POST with *Content-Type = application/json* the only integer parameter values in the Parameter list get deserialized. String values will be null. For example:

```
{
   "ParameterList": {
    "Id": 1,
    "Surname": "Nyanga"
  }
}
```

will have an Id value of 1 and a Surname value of null.

This issue only arises when I POST with json Content-Type. If POST form data it gets deserialized properly.

**NOTE**: This issue only started after I upgraded ServiceStack from **4.5.8** to **5.1.0**. It's been working fine for the past 4-5 years with previous versions.

Comment: I fixed it by adding `JsConfig.TryToParsePrimitiveTypeValues = true;` to my AppHost